# "Show desktop" button for Windows XP similar to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop, shortcuts

Windows 7's "Show Desktop" button (the little rectangle on the lower right corner of screen) is easier for me to use whereas XP's is located somewhere at the right side of Start button. Is it possible to create a "Show Desktop" rectangle for XP similar to the one on Windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this [*Get Windows 7 “Show Desktop” Taskbar Icon in Windows XP & Vista*](http://www.askvg.com/get-windows-7-show-desktop-taskbar-icon-in-windows-xp-vista/) will contain the facts you want. It works really in my XP machine by using [that](http://www.deviantart.com/download/133022210/Show_Desktop_by_CeIIular.rar).

[image: Show desktop taskbar icon]

Comment: Excellent tool. Does it automatically start with Windows or should I add it to XP's startup folder?

Comment: yes, once you add it to start up folder, it'll be with the system ever. :)

Comment: Actual source: http://ceiiular.deviantart.com/art/Show-Desktop-133022210

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, a keyboard shortcut: Windows key and 'D'? This shows the desktop; press once more to show your applications again.

Or Windows-M to minimize all windows, which can be undone using Shift-Windows-M.

Comment: I know about this. This is not what I ask for.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Windows-M` and `Shift-Windows-M`. Show desktop lacks the ability to restore windows prior to showing desktop and then clicking on an icon to lunch another program.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your `Quick Launch` toolbar to the right of the screen, but only as far as the left hand side of the clock and systray. You may need to unlock it first.

[image]

Comment: I don't have Windows to test, but can't one create *additional* Quick Launch toolbars? Then one could drag a new toolbar that only has the Show Desktop icon to the right, and leave the original next to the Start button?

Comment: Nope. Windows itself does not have such capabilities. Of course, then you install additional programs...

Comment: By adding additional programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new toolbar holding only one icon (or more shortcuts and stuff) for the "show desktop" jobby:

- Make a new folder somewhere and copy into it the "Show Desktop" from `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`.
- Right-click on the taskbar and select Toolbars -> New toolbar, then browse and select your folder holding the "Show Desktop".
- Right-click on the taskbar and unlock it (if it isn't already unlocked), make sure the new toolbar is in the right place, clear the "show text" and "show title" ticks, make the toolbar as small as possible<sup>†</sup>, and then relock the taskbar (if required).

[image: Extra toolbar to the right]

<sup><sup>†</sup> You can make a toolbar a bit smaller than you might think, as after locking the taskbar the little drag-handle disappears, which hence does not need any space. So, try to resize the toolbar to be a few pixels too small to fit the icon, and see if it fits after locking the taskbar.</sup>